# Asp.net (MVC) authentication cookie lost on redirect -- but only on Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, cookies

Scratching my head on this one. I set an authentication cookie and then do a redirect and everything works fine EXCEPT for Firefox. I can see the cookie get added but then removed once the redirect is complete.  This works fine on Edge, Chrome, Safari and Firefox on localhost but Fails only on Firefox on Azure server. Any ideas?

```
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            0,                                      // ticket version
            userid,                                 // authenticated user id
            DateTime.Now,                           // Issue date
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),         // Expiration date
            true,                                  // true to persist across browser sessions
            "",                               // can be used to store additional user data
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);   // path         

        // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
        string cipherText = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        if (null != cipherText)
        {
            // Add the cookie to the request to save it
            cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cipherText);
            //cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            cookie.Secure = true;

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userid, true);
        }

        Response.Redirect("~/app/dashboard", false);
```

Update:

So a bit more digging. This is deployed on azure and actually works on the deployment slot but fails (with Firefox) on production. When I swap the slots (which re-maps the ip address), the app no longer works (cookies no longer persist).

Comment: Would `cipherText` ever be null?

Comment: @mason - no. Have checked that. Also the cookie is small so I'm not exceeding any limits with FF.

Comment: @BriansaysReinstateMonica  yes.  I didn't write it but that put me off also.

Comment: If you know that `ciperText` will never be null - why do you check to make sure it's not null in the code? If it is null, it will silently redirect without setting the auth cookie, which I don't think you want.

Comment: @mason ok I've omitted some code for clarity but good point.

Comment: Could this possibly be some browser setting? Can you reproduce this from a Firefox browser on a different machine?

Comment: @howcheng I thought it might but it looks like it also happens on Chrome/Android. I've also run incognito with no luck. This is doing my head in!